# grep: Trailing backslash

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want to do a grep for `\resources\`. How do I do this?

I've tried:

```
grep \resources\
grep \\resources\\
grep "\resources\"
grep "\\resources\\"
```

[None of these work](http://xkcd.com/1638/).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The backslash is a special character for many applications:

- including the shell: you need to escape it using another backslash or more elegantly, using *single* quotes when possible:

  ```
  $ printf '%s\n' foo\\bar 'foo\bar'
  foo\bar
  foo\bar
  ```

  Here the command received two arguments with value `foo\bar`, which were echoed as-is on the terminal.

  (Above, I used `printf` instead of `echo` as many `echo` implementations also do their own interpreting of backslash (here would expand `\b` into a backspace character)).
- But backslash is also a special character for `grep`. This command recognizes many special sequences like `\(`, `\|`, `\.`, and so on. So similarly you need to feed grep with a double `\\` for an actual backslash character. This means that using the shell you need to type:

  ```
  grep 'foo\\bar'
  ```

  or equivalently:

  ```
  grep foo\\\\bar
  ```

  (both lines tell the shell to transmit `foo\\bar` as argument to `grep`).
- Many other commands interpret backslashes in some of their arguments… and two levels of escaping are needed (one to escape the shell interpretation, one to escape the command interpretation).

---

By the way, for the shell, single quotes `'…'` prevent any kind of character interpretation, but double quotes only prevents some of them: in particular `$`, `` ` `` and `\` remain active characters within `"…"`.

Answer (score 33):

You can also use `fgrep` (which is just `grep` with the `-F` flag).  This forces grep to interpret the pattern as a fixed string (i.e. it'll treat a `\` as a literal `\`). You'll still need to protect the backslashes from expansion by the shell.

```
grep -F '\resources\'
```

Comment: The flag is there for a reason! I was trying to grep for ``..\`` and even with ``'..\\'`` I didn't get the results I wanted. `grep -F '..\'` got me what I wanted! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`grep` requires *four* backslashes to represent a backslash:

```
grep "\\\\resources\\\\"
```

Comment: This is a rather misleading oversimplification.  `grep` only requires 1 backslash to escape another backslash, but the shell also requires backslashes to be quoted.  Double quotes (`"`) do NOT quote backslashes, but backslash does, which is why the double quotes in your example do nothing and the 4 backslashes are needed instead.

Comment: I had to use four backslashes in Windows even though the Windows command-prompt does not treat backslashes like *nix does. I wonder if the [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) ports misunderstood the shell’s effect and hard-coded a 4-slash requirement, thinking it was what was required by `grep`.

Comment: Depending on the shell, the string in double quotes is interpreted and not taken literally. The result of this step is passed on to grep. When \\\\resources\\\\ is being interpreted, it will result in \\resources\\ and that is what is passed on to grep.